# UV Texture coordinates out of [0,1] (WebGL)

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm creating a 3D game with *WebGL* and i'm using [Wavefront Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) as a base model format.
I recently found some models, their texture coordinates of which are out of the typical **[0,1]** range and i really don't know how to handle them (in code).

I know of course this is a known issue, texture coordinates can be outside of **[0,1]** and the solution is to use **GL_REPEAT** wrap mode.

But this is no solution to me since i have a lot of non-powered-by-2 textures and i need to use **CLAMP_TO_EDGE** wrap mode (the solution to non-pow-2 textures).

I tried to bypass this issue by coding, so to convert **[0-,1+]** ranges into **[0,1]** but with not much of success (although somewhat). Here's what i did:
I looped **"vt"** entries (from my parser) and the cases i'm checking are these (pseudo):

```
U,V = texture coordinates as they come from file

if (U<0) {
   U = U + Math.abs( Math.floor(U) );
}
if (U>1) {
   U = U - Math.floor(U);
}
if (V>=0) {
   V = Math.ceil(V) - V;
}
if (V<0) {
   V = Math.abs( Math.floor(V) - V );
}
```

The above fragment will take a U,V of *unknown range* and will convert it into **[0,1]**, taking also care the *WebGL texture coordination system* (*0,0* buttom-left for WebGL but *0,1* for Wavefront, the 3rd case above)

The numbers are calculated correctly but the result is not the expected and i'm afraid there is a misunderstanding by my side on how the **GL_REPEAT** mode works.

So my question(s)

- Can this be solved by code, so i can use **CLAMP_TO_EDGE**?
- In case there's no way, is there any program than can take a model of **REPEAT**-ed coordinates and produce one in **[0,1]** range? I'm already using *Blender* but could not find a setting for this in exporter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better off re-sizing your textures to the nearest power-of-two. You won't need to adjust the texture coordinates as they are relative to the size of the texture image (although you may need to set v = 1 - v to account for the different origins).

The problem with wrapping the texture coordinates yourself is that filtering will not work correctly at the "seams" where a value goes suddenly from 1 -> 0.

Comment: Thanx, well i ended up by resizing all of my textures of my paid models. I am quite surprised there's no solution to this. In my opinion texture coordinates outside [0,1] are just wrong and weird and there's no solution for converting, yet Open/Web GL REPEAT mode is the default. I'm confused but hey, thanx for clearing that out :)